# Error while trying to remove an element from a struct field

Tags: matlab, struct, runtime-error

I have the following code in `matlab` and trying to remove an element from a struct:

```
function test()
    C = struct;
    C.(sprintf('Ck')) = [1 6 8 9; 8 6 9 7; 7 6 67 6; 65 7 8 7];
    ck_length = length(C.(sprintf('Ck')));
    for i=1:ck_length
        if C.(sprintf('Ck'))(i)> 10
           cleared = rmfield(C.(sprintf('Ck')), C.(sprintf('Ck'))(i));
        end
    end
end
```

But, when I run the program I get an error as shown below:

```
>> test
??? Error using ==> rmfield at 19
S must be a structure array.

Error in ==> test at 89
   cleared = rmfield(C.(sprintf('Ck')), C.(sprintf('Ck'))(i));
```

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you treating `C.Ck` as a matrix or a vector? what should happen to its shape once you discard elements larger than 10? Did you by any chance meant to se `numel` instead of `length`?

Comment: BTW, next time, try editing your questions instead of delete and re-post...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove an element from an array you can simply assign it to an empty array (`[]`):

```
C.Ck(ii) = []; % removed the ii-th element of C.Ck.
```

### A few comments:

1. Use [dynamic field names](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html) only when you need them to be **dynamic**. If the field name is always `Ck` it is much better to access it as `C.Ck` than `C.(sprintf('Ck'))`.
2. Try not [to use `i` and `j` as variable names in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab).
3. If you are using `ii` as an index to `C.Ck` inside a `for` loop it is a bit risky to change the size of `C.Ck` inside the loop. (See e.g., [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832020/change-for-loop-index-variable-inside-the-loop)).
4. If you just want to discard elements of `C.Ck` that are larger than 10, all you need is

   ```
   C.Ck( C.Ck > 10 ) = [];
   ```

   or

   ```
   cleared = C.Ck( C.Ck <= 10 );
   ```

Comment: Is there a way to remove a **specific** element? For example, only `67`? Is there a way to do that? I think this would work: `
C.Ck(C.Ck == 67) = []`? Thanks

Comment: @Med-SWEng - you are correct. But would happen to the shape of your matrix if you remove a single element? Try that in Matlab and see what happens...